# Sonar Quality Gate behavior in Jenkins pipeline is unstable

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have some pipelines in Jenkins, with the SonarQube stage (Version: 6.7.1, build 35068).
In some builds it is aborted due to time out:

```
12:19:01 Sleeping for 3 min 0 sec
[Pipeline] timeout
12:22:10 Timeout set to expire in 25 min
[Pipeline] waitForQualityGate
12:22:10 Checking status of SonarQube task 'XXXXXXXXX' on server 'Sonar'
12:22:10 SonarQube task 'XXXXXXXXXX' status is 'PENDING'
12:47:10 Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
```

and in some other builds it pass:

```
13:56:47 Sleeping for 3 min 0 sec
[Pipeline] timeout
13:59:47 Timeout set to expire in 25 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] waitForQualityGate
13:59:47 Checking status of SonarQube task 'XXXXXXXXXX' on server 'Sonar'
13:59:47 SonarQube task 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' status is 'SUCCESS'
13:59:47 SonarQube task 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' completed. Quality gate is 'WARN'
```

what might be the reason for it? how can I keep it stable? can it be network issue?

Comment: Which SonarQube edition do you use? Enterprise? Community? How many projects uses the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waitForQualityGate` performs an [HTTP](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/scanner/jenkins/pipeline/WaitForQualityGateStep.java#L224) call to the SonarQube server.

Make sure your build nodes, both master and slaves has HTTP access to your SonarQube instance.

Comment: Ok, but still, how does it explain the fact it sometimes pass and sometimes not? Network?

Comment: Sometimes it runs on a node that can access sometimes not? Maybe your master node has access but not your slaves.

Comment: I think it always running on the same node

Comment: I got some general direction here: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-quality-gate-behavior-in-jenkins-pipeline-is-unstable/18020/2